# How to deduce V from (U → V ), (¬U→V) using Deduction theorem?

Tags: logic, deduction

We have these axioms and modus ponens:

Axiom 1 is: P→(Q→P)

Axiom 2 is: (P→(Q→R))→((P→Q)→(P→R))

Axiom 3 is:(P→Q)→(¬Q→¬P)

Modus ponens is: from P and P→Q infer Q

Edit: I still couldn't solve it, so I would really appreciate it if someone gave me a hint

Using these axioms and modus penons I want to infer V from (U → V ), (¬U→V)

Using axiom 3 I said that (V→ (U → V ) )    →     (¬ (U →V ) → ¬V ).
And using axiom 1 I said that V→ (U → V ).
So using modus ponens we can infer that ¬ (U →V ) → ¬V.

If I could somehow write ¬ (U →V ) using one of these axioms then I could infer ¬V.

I'm a bit stuck here. Any help please?

Comment: Welcome to SE Philosophy! Thanks for your contribution. Please take a quick moment to take the [tour](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/tour) or find [help](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/help). You can perform [searches here](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/search) or seek additional clarification at the [meta site](https://philosophy.meta.stackexchange.com/). Don't forget, when someone has answered your question, you can click on the checkmark to reward the contributor.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this is not a homework forum

Comment: It's not homework

Comment: The formula in question is not derivable since the usual third axiom is the converse of the one given. 

Here’s a sketch of how you’d do it: assume ~V. Then, assume ~U. By modus ponens you’ll get V, and using axiom 1 and the new axiom 3 you get ~V->(V->~(P->(Q->P))). By two counts of modus ponens (MP) and an application of the Deduction Theorem (DT), you’ll get ~U->~(P->(Q->P)). By the new axiom three, this gives (P->(Q->P))->U, which yields U. So, we get V, and since V->(~P->(Q->P)), by MP and DT you’ll get ~V->~(P->Q->P)), which will yield V.